# PHP: How to iterate over array to retrieve incremental value (n, n+1, etc)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
$data = array(51729,49359,47548,8242,8124,8716,19610,18030,15698);
```

And a index number

```
$index = 3;
```

Is there a simple way to iterate over `$data` to get

```
$first = array(51729,8242,19610)
$second = array(49359,8124,18030)
$third = array(47548,8716,15698)
```

Is `array_chunk()` and then `foreach` the chunks the way to go?

Edit: Here is how I made it with `array_chunk()`

```
$data = array(51729,49359,47548,8242,8124,8716,19610,18030,15698);
$index = 3;
$chunks = array_chunk($data, $index);
$first = array();
$second = array();
$third = array();
foreach($chunks as $out) {
    $first[] = $out[0];
    $second[] = $out[1];
    $third[] = $out[2];
}
```

Edit 2: All of this is part of transforming a unidimensional array to multidimensional, naming will eventually be dynamic, based on values in array `$labels`. Index number is also going to change (`$index` is provided in original array).

Comment: How are you naming your result arrays? Will it always be three? Or are you doing that dynamically as well?

Comment: array chunk is the way to go yes, you can also dynamically declare variables (in php.. not many languages support that stuff though) as you iterate through your result. You are better off with the array of arrays but .. yknow.. just saying you CAN if you REALLY want, iterate through your result array and allocate them each to a variable

Comment: `list($first, $second, $third) = array_map(null, ...array_chunk($data, $index));`

Comment: What if `$index = 2;` or  `$index = 4;` ??

Comment: Then you don't use variable names like `$first`, `$second`, and `$third`; you use an enumerated array instead (which you should always do if you find that you're numbering your variables, generally a code smell) - `$result = array_map(null, ...array_chunk($data, $index));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it dynamically, you can create a multidimensional array.

```
// Your provided values
$data = array(51729,49359,47548,8242,8124,8716,19610,18030,15698);
$index = 3;

// Initialize your result array
$result = array();

// Loop through the array
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    // Assign every nth to the appropriate sub-array
    $result[$key % $index][] = $value;  
}

// Print for validation
print_r($result);
```

Provides:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51729
            [1] => 8242
            [2] => 19610
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 49359
            [1] => 8124
            [2] => 18030
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47548
            [1] => 8716
            [2] => 15698
        )

)
```

Comment: oops, I just added pretty much this exact answer. +1 (I deleted mine)

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to do this non-dynamically. i.e. it will always be named this way, you're looking to continuously iterate in this manner with little changing, then the following code will be sufficient.

```
$i = 1;
foreach($data as $arr){
 switch($i){
  case 1: 
   array_push($first, $arr);
   break;
  case 2: 
   array_push($second, $arr);
   break;
  case 3: 
   array_push($third, $arr);
   break;
 }

$i++;
if($i == 4){
$i = 1;
 }
}
```